# Presto SQL : Changing time zones using time zone string coming as a result of a query is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, amazon-athena, presto

I am connecting to AWS Athena through Mode Analytics Platform and querying a table using its Query Engine ( which is based on Presto 0.172 ). This table `public.zones` has time zone information stored in a column called `time_zone` on some regions I am interested in, stored as `varchar`.

For example if I type:

```
SELECT time_zone 
FROM public.zones
LIMIT 4;
```

I get (as expected):

```
time_zone
----------  
US/Pacific 
US/Eastern 
US/Eastern 
US/Eastern
```

I can run this test query:

```
SELECT 
  timestamp '2017-06-01 12:34:56.789' AT TIME ZONE 'US/Eastern' AS time_eastern,
  time_zone 
FROM public.zones
LIMIT 4;
```

and I get (as expected)

```
time_eastern                        time_zone
----------------------------------  ----------
2017-06-01 08:34:56.789 US/Eastern  US/Pacific
2017-06-01 08:34:56.789 US/Eastern  US/Eastern
2017-06-01 08:34:56.789 US/Eastern  US/Eastern
2017-06-01 08:34:56.789 US/Eastern  US/Eastern
```

Now, I want to represent the same time string `'2017-06-01 12:34:56.789'` in different time zones that I query from the zones table. I expected the following query to run. (It runs on PostgreSQL).

```
SELECT 
  timestamp '2017-06-01 12:34:56.789' AT TIME ZONE time_zone AS time_custom,
  time_zone 
FROM public.zones
LIMIT 4;
```

I get the following error:

```
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. 
line 2:52: no viable alternative at input 'TIME ZONE time_zone'
```

What is the reason for this not working in Presto SQL / AWS Athena Query Engine ?

Can anyone suggest any work-arounds or what is my syntactical error if any?

Comment: It works in PostgreSQL. Maybe use real PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AT TIME ZONE` accepts only literal or interval.

Presto 320 adds [`with_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#with_timezone) (for `timestamp` values) [`at_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#at_timezone) (for `timestamp with time zone` values) exactly for this purpose.

If you are using older Presto version (such as Athena as of this writing), you can use following workaround. You can cast your timestamp value to a `varchar`, concatenate with zone and cast to `timestamp with time zone`.

```
presto> select cast(cast(t as varchar) || ' ' || zone as timestamp with time zone)
  from (values (timestamp '2017-06-01 12:34:56.789', 'US/Pacific')) x(t, zone);
                    _col0
---------------------------------------------
 2017-06-01 12:34:56.789 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```

(Note: tested on Presto 320. If this doesn't work on Athena yet, let me know.)

Comment: Thank you for such a great answer. Both the "right" answer in the future *and* a workaround for _today_.