# Presto: I have a column in the same table as the data which specifies the time zone I want to offset my dates to

Tags: sql, presto, timezone-offset, case-when

I have a table which has the following columns:

```
Store  timezone              date_entry        date_exit
ABC    America/Los Angeles   1/1/2019 16:17    1/4/2019 16:17 
DEF    Central Standard Time 2/1/2019 13:12    2/15/2019 09:45
```

All the date_entry and date_exit are in UTC and I want to convert it to the desired timezone as specified in the timezone column. This is just a sample, I have data for multiple timezones and hard coding it is very cumbersome and time consuming. Is there a way in Presto where I can input this string from timezone column to offset the time to the desired timezone?

Currently I am doing this:

```
date_entry AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' AS date_entry
```

With CASE WHEN statements, Is there a way to use the timezone column to do this without case when in Presto?

I have looked into these questions and tried the prospective solutions and it did not work for me:

1) [Can you use a column for the timezone parameter of AT TIME ZONE in Presto / Athena?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446184/can-you-use-a-column-for-the-timezone-parameter-of-at-time-zone-in-presto-athe)
2) [Presto SQL : Changing time zones using time zone string coming as a result of a query is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230931/presto-sql-changing-time-zones-using-time-zone-string-coming-as-a-result-of-a)

Answer (score 2):

Presto 320 adds [`with_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#with_timezone) (for `timestamp` values) [`at_timezone`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#at_timezone) (for `timestamp with time zone` values) exactly for this purpose.

This is equivalent of (hypothetical) `AT TIME ZONE x` where `x` is not constant.